# Emails, a different 'reply to' address than sender address

Tags: django, email, contact-form

I have a `contact form` on a website (a general form: *name*, *email*, *subject*, *message*) in which mails are sent using *google apps* smtp to the admins.
Currently if an administrator wants to reply to the mail directly selecting the reply option, the person's reply's *To* field will be filled by the sender's address automatically.

What I wan't to ask is, **Is there any standardized way to pass on some additional info with the mail which would define any reply to the mail should go to this address instead of the sender's?**

It does seems that there is a little chance for this option as it may lead to some problems due to spammers (They may define a custom reply field in their mail and a general user might not look where they are replying).

So as an alternative what I thought is to find a way to create a filter with sender's account which figures out the reply email address from the format and forwards the mail (Doesn't seems like a good solution and I have no idea how to achieve this).

I have tagged django, though this is not directly related with this, as I will finally implement this through django.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are in fact standardized headers to specify response headers: http://cr.yp.to/immhf/response.html.

As far as implementing this in Django is concerned, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) contains an example:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello', # email subject
    'Body goes here', # email body
    'from@example.com', # sender address
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    headers={'Reply-To': 'another@example.com'},
)
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Note that [in Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage), a new `reply_to` parameter has been added to the `EmailMessage` object.

Answer (score 4):

Reply-To is a standard SMTP header.

I can't find a good reference for it at the moment, but it is mentioned in the Wikipedia article on [Email](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email).

Edit: Found it: [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt), section 3.6.2

Comment: thanks @david, Found the reply to specs in the appendix A.2; Can't this be a little dangerous if spammers spoof the reply to email address?

Comment: No more than spoofing the from address, which they are already doing. But to the best of my knowledge, most spam is an advertisement, not intended to be replied to, so I don't think the Reply-To address matters much.

Answer (score 2):

The RFC says you can specify multiple emails and that is what I was looking for. Came up with this:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
headers = {'Reply-To': 'email@one.com;email@two.com'}
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, EMAIL_HOST_USER, email_list, headers=headers)
msg.content_subtype = "html"
msg.send()
```

Works like a charm. Note: EMAIL_HOST_USER is imported from your settings file as per Django doc email setup. More on this here, search for 'reply-to': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/

Answer (score 0):

Here is also how reply-to can be used

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage(
    'Hello',
    'Body goes here',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'],
    ['bcc@example.com'],
    reply_to=['another@example.com'],
    headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'},
)
```

Read more at docs [docs.djangoproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects)